# Creating new blazor application throws an error when run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I am following [Get started with Blazor](https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html). I have created the application and attempt to run it as is i have made no changes.

[image]

There are three things in my event log.

- The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.
- Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WEBAPPLICATION1' with physical root 'C:\Users\LindaL\source\repos\Daimto.RazorTest.Tools\WebApplication1\' failed to start process with commandline 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\web tools\projectsystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\LindaL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF272.tmp"', ErrorCode = '0x80004005' : 0.
- Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WEBAPPLICATION1' with physical root 'C:\Users\LindaL\source\repos\Daimto.RazorTest.Tools\WebApplication1\' failed to start process with commandline 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\web tools\projectsystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\LindaL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF272.tmp"', ErrorCode = '0x80004005' : 0.

Note i just update to visual studio professional 2017 15.9.3.  I have used blazor before this was working fine.

**Update:** This appears only in the "Blazor" project type.

**Update2:** hitting Cntrl-F5 as opposed to just F5 – No change.

**Update3** Project file per request in comment in answer below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RunCommand>dotnet</RunCommand>
    <RunArguments>blazor serve</RunArguments>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser" Version="0.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="0.6.0" PrivateAssets="all" />

    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli" Version="0.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: No change hitting Cntrl-F5 as opposed to just F5

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/11/05/tracking-down-a-mysterious-502-5-error-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Did you update your Blazor Language Services extension if you had installed before?

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, the docs say that, but except for reload without (explicitly) recompiling, things _do_ work when using F5.   That's why when I was curious why reloading wasn't working (and only reloading) I was surprised to discover that guidance.  That said, there's no _advantage_ to running with the debugger, but everything basically works in my experience.

Comment: @Wanton I have been using Blazor for two or three weeks now i installed it by following this https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html  Yes Language Services extension was installed at the time.   I am not exactly sure how to figure out if their are updates and install them.   Should i assume that VS would pick up new releases of Blazor?

Comment: @DaImTo did you try answer I posted? And yes VS usually notifies user if there are updates for extensions. You can also manually check your Tools/Extensions and Updates to see if there are any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete global.json and see if that helps.

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1342

If that doesn't help try adding global.json with content

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.500"
  }
}
```

If all fails, close all Visual Studio instances and reinstall Blazor templates with `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates` and create new Blazor solution with `dotnet new` and use Blazor template you want.

Comment: There is no global.json file in the project folder.

Comment: Adding global.json makes it stop crashing but i am getting 500 This page isn’t working. (Checked i have 2.1.500 sdk installed)

Comment: Does your .csproj have any `PackageReference` with preview in them? Like `Version="2.1.0-preview2-final"`. If you have try to change them to Version="2.1.0" and make sure your blazor package reference is 0.7.0

Comment: Update all `0.6.0` to `0.7.0` in your csproj.

Comment: You should have ASP.NET Core project in your solution. Check that it doesn't have any preview ASP.NET Core package references. Update them according to my previous post. If all fails, reinstall Blazor templates with `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates` and create new Blazor solution with `dotnet new` and use Blazor template you want.

Comment: Visual studio 2017 new project -> asp.net core web application -> Select blazer   It creates one project in the solution.    I would expect this to create the project correctly as thats what the template is for isnt it?   No where in any documentation does it mention having to edit a csproj file pr add a global.json i think its weird.

Comment: You still need to update your templates with `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates`. If you just created your Blazor solution you clearly have old templates because your Blazor version is 0.6.0.   Remember to have all Visual Studio instanced closed before reinstalling Blazor templates.

Comment: How do you install the newer version of blazor anyway :)

Comment: Blazor is a nuget package. Your csproj points to old 0.6.0 nuget. It should be 0.7.0. By updating templates with `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates` those updated templates have correct 0.7.0 nuget package reference. Plus those templates are designed to work with 0.7.0. There might be breaking changes between 0.6.0 and 0.7.0.